# Random (?) number generation in R using sample() always returning the same result

Tags: r, random

I am writing an R script (using RStudio on Ubuntu 18.04), and at a certain point I need to randomly pick (with no replacement) 123 random numbers between 1 and 1040. I do this with:

```
myvector[sample(1:1040,X,replace=F)] = 1
```

where 'myvector' is a 1040-long vector of 0s, and I need to replace 0 with 1 in X=123 random positions.

Every time I copy this exact line of code to the R console and run it, it works as I would expect, picking 123 different numbers at every iteration.

Strangely however, every time I execute the script containing this line of code, it instead picks the same 123 numbers.

At first, I thought this may be due to some trivial object saving/renaming bug, but even if I add

```
print(sample(1:1040,123,replace=F))
```

to the script, if picks always the same set of numbers (different from that picked by the code line above, but identical at every iteration).

I haven't invoked set.seed() anywhere within the script and/or ever since I switched the computer on, so I don't understand why it's behaving this way.

Any idea?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have a `.Rprofile` file? Maybe the seed is set there. Are you using external packages? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have loaded a previous workspace, the seed from that workspace is also loaded. This will give the same results every time you invoke `sample`.

Include this line

```
rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv())
```

before you call `sample`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the problem...I didn't know workspaces had a fixed seed...!